# Gnuplot : difference between Comma and Point as decimal sign in data

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm producing a heat map with gnuplot using **cbrange** and palette defined. I use the same min/max values in both options. However, values **-7,64** in my data are not shown as **red (D73628) but as orange**.

**-7,1** for example is shown in red. It seems as if the ranges are not working as I want to. I thought if I put the exact values in the palette defined and the min/max for cbrange, then the colours in the map would be the same for the values which I defined in palette defined.

```
set cbrange [-7.64:27]
set palette defined (-7.64 "#D73628", -6.79 "#FCF604", -4.95 "#63C05B", -3.11 "#0FA9C8", -1.27 "#543694", 0 "white", 1 "#EAEAEA", 27.0 "black" )
```

**Update**: I just found out that the problem is that in my data I used **7,64** instead of **7.64**. I don't know what the comma instead of the point does since the maps looked quite ok with them. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Where was the comma? In the `set cbrange` or in the `set palette`?

Comment: Does `set decimalsign locale; set decimalsign ","` solve your problem?

Comment: The comma was in the data, but in the `set cbrange` and `set palette` I used a point. Thanks for the suggestion vagoberto, actually my problem was solved by changing the point into a comma, but since I analysed many maps where I used a comma I'd like to know in which way the **.** instead of the **,** in the data changes the resulting map colors.

Comment: @vagoberto The option `set decimalsign ","` seems to format the printed numbers, but not the input data. For input data formatting you'd need to specify a locale. If the default one takes "." as decimal separator then it won't do anything to type `set decimalsign locale`.

Comment: @Meera Gnuplot is just ignoring what's after the comma, so 7,1 will be rounded down to 7. You can format your data on the fly using a bash command, e.g. `sed`, to preprocess your data: `plot "< sed 's/,/./g' datafile"`.